# How to make incremental builds of maven project

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

every time I build my `maven` project, I get something like this: `xxx-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`. I'd like to have something like `xxx-0.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar`, `xxx-0.0.3-SNAPSHOT.jar` etc, however a `.jar` that increments its name. I think, it can be done adding some plugin in `pom.xml`, but not yet figured out exactly how.

How can I do?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Snapshot builds are meant to be volatile, i.e. you can build `0.0.1-SNAPSHOT` as often as you like and when you reference `0.0.1-SNAPSHOT`, you get the newest version.

If you need versions with fixed numbers (like `0.0.1`), you build *releases*. This can e.g. be done by using the Maven release plugin. If you apply it to your version `0.0.1-SNAPSHOT`, then it builds `0.0.1` and makes a new commit to your git/svn to change the version number to `0.0.2-SNAPSHOT`.

Before you decide what to do you should analyse exactly what you want to achieve with your versioning scheme.